# Error AttributeError: module 'aiohttp' has no attribute 'ClientSession'

Tags: python, asynchronous, aiohttp

Error AttributeError: module 'aiohttp' has no attribute 'ClientSession', But ClientSession exists in module, idk how to solve it. i tried everthing someone help

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import json
import time

async def get_page (session,url): 
  async with session.get(url) as r:
   return await r.text()


async def get_all(session,urls) :
    tasks = []
    for url in urls:
        task = asyncio.create_task(get_page(session,url) )
        tasks.append(task)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

async def main (urls) :
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session : # Error here
        data = await get_all(session,urls)
        return data

def parse(results):
    for html in results:   
        data = json.loads(html)       
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ['https://www.google.com']
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    results = asyncio.run(main(urls))
    parse(results)
```

Comment: What version of aiohttp did you install?  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: File "c:\Users\WIndows\Desktop\aiohttp.py", line 90, in <module>
    results = asyncio.run(main(urls))
  File "C:\Users\WIndows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\WIndows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\WIndows\Desktop\aiohttp.py", line 55, in main
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session :
AttributeError: module 'aiohttp' has no attribute 'ClientSession'

Comment: Please include that in your post.

Comment: 3.8.1 aiohttp version

Comment: Are you running this script in C:\Users\Windows\Desktop?

Comment: the python file is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you've named the script `aiohttp.py` which interferes with python's ability to use the aiohttp module.

Rename that file to `aiohttp_custom.py` (or something else) and your problem should be gone.